# TypeScript compiler: error reading file

Tags: typescript, file-not-found

When I compile my ASP.NET MVC4 project I get the following compiler warnings, even though these files are present in the project.

4>  Error reading file "C:\Users\nji\WebSites\TestTypeScript\Scripts\Policies\CallbackPolicy.ts": File not found
4>  Error reading file "C:\Users\nji\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\WebSites\TestTypeScript\Scripts\ViewModels\VectoLayerViewModel.ts": File not found

Errors do not seem to affect code during runtime.

Anyone run into this?

Comment: Im seeing this as well recently. After I upgraded to web essesntials 1.9.1. The files are there, everything seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

Do those files actually exist? This error would normally be caused by the files either being moved or deleted - so the path would be incorrect.

If you navigate to:

```
C:\Users\nji\WebSites\TestTypeScript\Scripts\Policies\
```

Can you see `CallbackPolicy.ts`?

At runtime, you will be referencing the `.js` files, which may be in the correct location even if the `.ts` file is gone.